# c++: invalid conversion from `const char* const' to `char*'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

![complation error]

I get this compliation error over and over again, no matter what I change in the relevant line. As you can see, it sends me to **stl_iterator.h** file.

I have no clue on what the problem could be.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you even using `vector<char>`?

Comment: You should include the code where the error appears (as text), with the declarations of the elements involved. It is quite hard to try and read from the image.

Comment: Please just copy and paste, there is no need to screenshot

Comment: At least if I'm reading it correctly, a substantial part of your code is basically attempting to implement `std::remove_copy_if`.

Comment: You guys are complaining about the screenshot, but you're missing one important consideration: what if the OP is actually coding in Paint? To the OP: you should consider upgrading or replacing Dev-C++. The version you're using is very old, outdated and buggy. See this for more info on updating or alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`punc_vec` is `const`, so you must use a `const_iterator`.

Comment: +1 but if you have C++11 then you might want to consider auto.

Comment: @111111: From the screenshot we can see that galeck is using GCC 3.4.2, which does not support `auto`.

Comment: @Mankarse, then we should probably recommend a compiler update 3.4 is OLD.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `punc_vec` is declared `const`, and so `punc_vec.begin()` is returning a `const_iterator`, rather than an `iterator`. Change the line to:

```
for(std::vector<char>::const_iterator i_vec=(punc_vec).begin();/*...*/)
```